# The reason behind fusion of jets

Tags: aerodynamics

I was looking at jet planes flying in the sky and noticed their two jets seem to project in a diverging direction at the end of the engines, but they reunite later.
I am posting two example photographs to show what I saw.
[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]
What is the reason behind this diverging then converging cloud formation in the sky?
I have hypotheses but too far fetched (temperature would make gases spread if high, but converge when it gets colder: this is compatible with diffusion speed but not displacement imho).

Comment: Merging may just be the visible result of diffusion.  Evaporation rate will be higher at the outer boundary.  Wouldn't required anything to "converge".

Comment: Can you prove it?

Comment: No, hence a comment rather than an answer.  But it's an idea that just because they appear to converge doesn't mean that air parcels are moving that way.  There will be rotation vortices coming off the wings, so there is plenty of motion. Aviation SE may have more practical information.